# StarTeam: Error during file delta checkout

Tags: starteam

Every time I try to check out an "Out Of Date" file, I receive the following error: "Error during file delta checkout". If I delete the file in my working directory, the file now appears to be "missing" in the StarTeam client and I can do a check out without any problems. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running 2009R2, make sure "Optimize for slow connections" is turned off under Tools, Personal Options, File.  That should prevent your client from requesting deltas.

http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.stserver.doc%2Fhtml%2Fhives.htm

As to the root cause of the delta retrieve error, that is probably a MicroFocus support issue.  On older versions of StarTeam where deltas were kept (pre-2005), upgrades to certain server versions/patches could raise a similar error.  Fixes ranged from cleaning out the cache directory on the server to running custom scripts from Borland to fix broken DB references.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. That fixed my problem!